# Will using a car charger degrade my phone's battery?

Tags: battery, charging, htc-8x

Now that the Nokia Drive app is out for my 8X, I'm considering getting a car mount and charger so it can replace my GPS device. I've been told that using a car charger can degrade my phone's battery, but I'm having trouble finding any credible source online.

For a modern phone like the HTC 8X, will using a car charger degrade my battery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The car charger will have the same output as a standard charger, so no problems there.

The degradation people are mentioning is probably due to the car kit frequently charging your phone to 100% which [isn't good](http://blogs.tribune.com.pk/story/15555/having-difficulties-prolonging-your-cell-phone-battery-life-stop-charging-it/) for lithium-ion batteries. I believe most phones will stop charging when it gets to 100%, but the problem will be that you may frequently turn your car on/off for short stops, so your phone will dip below 100% and resulting in frequent charges to 100%.

A solution would be to only put it on the charger when it gets below 50%.

Comment: Apparently you want to avoid a dirt cheap charger to ensure that the output is a constant 5 volts. But I think that advice holds true for any accessory.